# Vimeo square videos are small on mobile

Tags: video, vimeo, square

If you publish a square video the player size if you embed it is still 16:9ratio. On mobile these videos are small. Is there a way to override the ratio so it will be 1:1?

https://blankframes.com/project/vitahustle/

[image]